# Sum product by row across two dataframes/matrix in r

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, cross-product

I have two data frames, each with two columns.  They could be matrices with same dimensions if that helps in the calculations.

What I want to do is the sum product of these data frames of the respective positions/rows.

For example the solution would be the following in one column.

```
 21 = 1*1+10*2
 42 = 2*1 +20*2
63 = 3*1 + 20*2

 a=data.frame(c_1=c(1,2,3),c_2=c(10,20,30))
  b=data.frame(c2_1=c(1,1,1),c2_2=c(2,2,2))
```

Comment: you can use > crossproduct function in R. It is pretty straight forward function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try something like

```
rowSums(a*b)
[1] 21 42 63
```